# RecyclerView с 3 вертикальными элементами и c горизонтальной прокруткой

Tags: java, android, kotlin, recyclerview

Как сейчас реализовывают такой вот RecyclerView с горизонтальной прокруткой как на скриншоте?

То есть при пролистывании вправо, у нас отобразятся еще "три вертикальных элемента" (на скрине изображение как раз вылазит от следующих трех элементов):

[image: ...]

Comment: у вас в айтеме должен быть горизонтальный ресайклер вью и в onBindViewHolder вы Создаете вложенный адаптер и добавляете туде 3 своих элемента и все

Answer (score -1):

Для того чтобы задать направление скролла у RecyclerView можно использовать `LinearLayoutManager`.

**Kotlin:**

Для начала его объявим:

```
val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

ключевым здесь является `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL`. Дальше берем ваш список и крепим к нему данный layoutManager:

```
rvList.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

так же стоит указать что список имеет фиксированный размер элементов:

```
rvList.setHasFixedSize(true)
```

ну и дальше крепите к нему адаптер с данными:

```
rvList.adapter = ...
```

**JAVA:**

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView rvList= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
rvList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Вот принцип его принцип работы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот [туториал](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview), [статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/434024/) и [подобный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview).

Comment: список не будет скроллиться вертикально, только горизонтально. Обычная горизонтальная прокрутка, только вместо обычного 1 элемента, нужно три элемента разместить по вертикали

Comment: @Anton, то есть будет только 3 элемента и это максимум?

Comment: да, и что то мне кажется всё это реализовывается через какой нибудь GridView / GridLayout

Comment: ну если не заморачиваться на счет адаптера и заполнения его данными, то можно и вручную все загрузить туда и все :)

Comment: действительно, как я раньше до этого не додумался, серьезно?)